# Comparing two different arrayList

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, constructor

this is my first time using stackFlow, and i need help
    i am kind of new to programming.
    i have a method that i created which asks the points made and the points lost for each game a team plays. i want someone to explain what i need to do, thats all, or if its not possible this way
    I want to store the name of the teams in an arrayList.

how do i get it to ask, What is Arsenal pointsMade, What is Arsenal pointsLost, and What it liverpool pointsMade and pointsLost? please, if you dont understand my question, let me know so i can rephrase it better. Thanks.

```
public class projectscore
{
  public int pointsMade;
  public int pointsLost;
  public projectscore(int pointsM, int pointsL)
  {
   pointsMade = pointsM;`enter code here`
   pointsLost = pointsL;
  }

  public void setpointsMade(int pointsM)
  {
    pointsMade = pointsM;

  }
  public void setpointsLost(int pointsL)
  {

    pointsLost = pointsL;

  }
  public int getpointsMade()
  {
    return pointsMade;

  }
  public int getpointsLost()
  {

    return pointsLost;

  }
  public void getfinalScore()
  {

   System.out.println(pointsMade);
   System.out.println(pointsLost);
  }
}

import java.util.*;
public class fProjectScore
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    projectscore pscore = new projectscore(0, 0);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("what is the points made today ");
    Integer temp = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("what is the points lost today ");
    Integer temp2 = in.nextInt();


    pscore.setpointsMade(temp);
    pscore.setpointsLost(temp2);

 /*   HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(temp, temp2);
   */ 
    if(temp > temp2)
    {
      System.out.println("winner"); 
    }
    else  if(temp < temp2)
    {
      System.out.println("losser"); 
    }
    else  if(temp == temp2)
    {
      System.out.println("Tie Game"); 
    }
}
}

i want to add this to my main method 
 ArrayList<String>participants = new ArrayList<String>();
participants.add("Arsenal");
participants.add("Liverpool);

how do i get it to ask, What is Arsenal pointsMade, What is Arsenal pointsLost, and What it liverpool pointsMade and pointsLost? please, if you dont understand my question, let me know so i can rephrase it better. Thanks.
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand, a little more explanation please?

Comment: how do i make the method see the arrayList participants? i want to use the element in the arrayList to ask What is the point "Arsenal made"? What is the point "Arsenal Lost"? so for each element in the arrayList, i want the questions to be asked. english isnt really my first language so i have problem explaining in depth. If i have 10 elements in the arraylist, i want it to ask the question for each one of them.

Comment: or am i going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Oh, well I assume you've heard of the Java API? You can use the one on ArrayList to find out the method, here, this the link. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you read up on Object-oriented programming, and create a class for the Teams.

Here's some pseudo code. Not tested, but it should give you an idea of what I mean.

```
public class Team {
    int points;
    final String name;

    public Team(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public void setPoints(int p) { this.points = p; }
    public int getPoints() { return this.points; }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}

void main() {
    Team arsenal = new Team("Arsenal");
    Team liverpool = new Team("Liverpool");
    ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
    teams.add(arsenal);
    teams.add(liverpool);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(Team team : teams) {
        System.out.println("How many points did " + team.getName() + " made today");
        Integer points = in.nextInt();
        team.setScore(points);
    }

    // Sort the teams by score somehow
    teams.sort()

    // Get the winners 
    ArrayList<List> winners = this.getWinners(teams)

    if (winners.count > 1) {
        // It's a draw between the ones in the winners arraylist
    } else {
        println("The winner is: " + winners.get(0).name)
    }
}
```